# Deleting From Multiple Tables When There Are Unmatched Records

Tags: mysql

I have a query using mysql that looks like this:

```
Delete A, B, C 
FROM FROM  A 
INNER JOIN B 
ON         A.a = B.a 
INNER JOIN C 
ON         B.c = C.c 
WHERE      A.a = 'value'.
```

This query works fine if matching records are found.
But in my case, there could be scenarios where matching records might not be found on table B and C. When this happens I still want the record on table A to still be deleted.
I have seen the option of deleting from the tables one after the other, but that process is long and hectic.
Any help on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the join to B and C optional then you should use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`.

For example, a query like this should accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
 Delete A, B, C 
 FROM  A 
 LEFT JOIN B 
 ON         A.a = B.a 
 LEFT JOIN C 
 ON         B.c = C.c 
 WHERE      A.a = 'value'
```